# HTML5 file upload and canvas on IOS6

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, ios6

I'm writing an little script to perform some modification on an image before uploading it with the canvas api.

All was perfect before I test it on IOS6. When you choose to take a file from your camera on portrait mode, when i insert the blob in the canvas, the image is not on the good orientation and deformed.

If you have IOS6 you can test it here :

http://jsfiddle.net/uKnAR/3/

It is a IOS6 bug or something got wrong in my code ?

Thank you !

Comment: I am finding the same thing here. I have completed an implementation that seems to have the same affect here http://jsfiddle.net/Untd8/

Comment: And I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Happy to know i'm not alone ! I haven't found an solution yet :(

Comment: Same problem here. I could get it to display at the correct size by forcing the height to a arbitrary value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a solution here :
https://github.com/gokercebeci/canvasResize
demo : http://canvasresize.gokercebeci.com/

(via [IOS6 and Safari Photo Uploading - File API + Canvas + jQuery Ajax Uploading and Resizing Files Asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539862/ios6-and-safari-photo-uploading-file-api-canvas-jquery-ajax-uploading-and))