# iOS 6 Safari Image Upload - Orientation Wrong

Tags: ios, image, forms, upload, safari

I've built a web app which lets you upload a photo from the browser. When using this in iOS 6, photos seem to end up in landscape orientation even if they were taken in portrait when uploaded. Should I be doing some server side checks to get the image the right way round or is there some kind of iOS specific attributes/JavaScript I can apply to the upload form to fix this?

**Update**

As requested, here's the code I wrote to do this. Pre-requisites are that I'm using PHP and the WideImage library (this is a snippet from a much larger script so you could use something different for image manipulation if you like).

```
// Load Image Into Wide Image
$image=WideImage::load(IMG_UPLOAD_DIR.$result['name']);
$exif=exif_read_data(IMG_UPLOAD_DIR.$result['name']);
$orientation=$exif['Orientation'];
$result['orientation']=$orientation;

// Use Wide Image To Resize Images
$full=$image->resize(IMG_FULL_H,IMG_FULL_H);
$thumb=$image->resize(IMG_THUMB_W,IMG_THUMB_H);

switch($orientation){
    case 2:
        $full->mirror()->saveToFile(IMG_UPLOAD_DIR.$result['name'], 90);
        $thumb->mirror()->saveToFile(IMG_UPLOAD_DIR.$thumbName, 90);
        break;

    case 3:
        $full->rotate(-180)->saveToFile(IMG_UPLOAD_DIR.$result['name'], 90);
        $thumb->rotate(-180)->saveToFile(IMG_UPLOAD_DIR.$thumbName, 90);
        break;

    case 4:
        $full->rotate(180)->mirror()->saveToFile(IMG_UPLOAD_DIR.$result['name'], 90);
        $thumb->rotate(180)->mirror()->saveToFile(IMG_UPLOAD_DIR.$thumbName, 90);
        break;

    case 5:
        $full->rotate(90)->mirror()->saveToFile(IMG_UPLOAD_DIR.$result['name'], 90);
        $thumb->rotate(90)->mirror()->saveToFile(IMG_UPLOAD_DIR.$thumbName, 90);
        break;

    case 6:
        $full->rotate(90)->saveToFile(IMG_UPLOAD_DIR.$result['name'], 90);
        $thumb->rotate(90)->saveToFile(IMG_UPLOAD_DIR.$thumbName, 90);
        break;

    case 7:
        $full->rotate(-90)->saveToFile(IMG_UPLOAD_DIR.$result['name'], 90);
        $thumb->rotate(-90)->saveToFile(IMG_UPLOAD_DIR.$thumbName, 90);
        break;

    case 8:
        $full->rotate(-90)->saveToFile(IMG_UPLOAD_DIR.$result['name'], 90);
        $thumb->rotate(-90)->saveToFile(IMG_UPLOAD_DIR.$thumbName, 90);
        break;

    default:
        $full->saveToFile(IMG_UPLOAD_DIR.$result['name'], 90);
        $thumb->saveToFile(IMG_UPLOAD_DIR.$thumbName, 90);
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the images `exif` metadata, iPhone camera takes 'rotated' images.

Comment: Thanks - grabbed the `exif` metadata and added some extra code to my image resize script and I'm done :)

Comment: I think the code used for this should be shared in this answer / question.

Comment: @eladleb I believe that will be a separate problem without universal solution. If you have particular question about reading exif data, please go ahead and create new question.

Comment: I'll add my code to an answer to this question as it's too long to add to a comment...

Comment: @edcs Thanks, detailed question is always appreciated. For everyone who could have a similar problem not using PHP or WideImage, please go ahead and create a separate question now when you understand the problem source.

Comment: Thanks so much for adding the fix in the question.  Saved me a ton of time.

Answer (score 2):

You might try this jQuery plugin ( at the bottom of this thread )

[IOS6 and Safari Photo Uploading - File API + Canvas + jQuery Ajax Uploading and Resizing Files Asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539862/ios6-and-safari-photo-uploading-file-api-canvas-jquery-ajax-uploading-and)

Answer (score 1):

As an extension to A-Live's answer:

If you are using ruby, RMagick has an `auto_orient` method.
From documentation:

> Rotates or flips the image based on the image's EXIF orientation tag.
>   Note that only some models of modern digital cameras can tag an image
>   with the orientation. If the image does not have an orientation tag,
>   or the image is already properly oriented, then auto_orient returns
>   an exact copy of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Worth noting that running your image through [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations) sorts this out.

Prior to routing through that service the photos I had taken with my iPhone would display as rotated (seemingly, without reason) *only on desktop*.

Once behind a Cloudinary url, *with*  *any* image transformation function, the image is returned in the proper orientation.

I'm using their paid service, but it seems as though they have a free tier.